# Tensorflow in python 3.9 Installation error : failure to install tensorflow [WinError 2]

Tags: python, python-3.9

While installing TensorFlow on Windows having python 3.9 installed using the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Following error occurred with the warning:

```
WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] 
The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\pyrsa-decrypt.exe'
-> 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\pyrsa-decrypt.exe.deleteme'
```

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Run the same command using

--user

```
pip install --user package_name
```

or you can try to restart the terminal and run it as admin

Answer (score 1):

Just run the cmd as an administrator then retype the command `pip install tensorflow`
it will take over from where the error occured.

Comment: This was already mentioned in the other answer. Is there a reason to post a new answer for it? You could upvote the other answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
When I am running google colab in local runtime jupyter, I tried next command and it worked for me:

```
!pip install --user tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be working for me on Windows Python 3.9 is:

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Just to get it to install without an error.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#:%7E:text=pip%20install%20--upgrade%20tensorflow). Its even working for a non virtual env on my end.